# AWS Cognito Users with Authorization (how to add a user to a user group from the application?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

I'm building an app with react on the front end and aws dynamodb + labmda on the back end to save data.  I'm using amplify to handle user authentication but I'm struggling with a good way to handle authorization.

I'd like to use the Cognito userpool groups but there does not appear to be a way to manage a user from my app because amplify does not support updating a user to place them in a group.  I'd really rather not expose the aws console login to the app administrator so it would seem i need to find a way in the app itself to handle this.

I could create a user table in dynamodb itself to hold a user profile which could have a field to hold the roles I want the user to be able to perform and then add a CRUD page for an admin user to update the profile of a non-admin user.  However, I don't particularly like this option because its really a duplication of data and because it doesn't also support a way to (easily) disable a user.

It does appear that a dynamodb table update can trigger a lambda function so I'd also considered somehow doing this to trigger the cognito userpool role addition for the user when the table is updated by the admin user on the CRUD page but I'm having a little trouble connecting all the dots on the trigger, the function and the permissions needed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a user to a group using the aws-sdk's adminAddUserToGroup. You could do this in a Lambda, and invoke that lambda however you like (API Gateway with Cognito authorizer, invoke lambda directly, invoke from DynamoDB Stream event). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminAddUserToGroup-property

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dylan, this is exactly what I've done.  I had mistakenly thought, that this could not be done with my user but after attempting this and tracing the failures, I was able to determine how to apply the correct policy to the role that was doing the addToGroup and removeFromGroup.

Thanks again,
Mike